# Powerapps Gallery 1st column sum in next column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I use the horizontal gallery and i want to do sum like 1`column data +second column data= display output in second column

[image]

Since the number of columns are dynamic they are not fixed/static so we were unable to find an optimal solution.

Comment: A thought... add an index to your collection (see https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Adding-an-index-column-to-a-collection/td-p/394941), then you could use something along the lines of: `Last(FirstN(yourCollection), ThisItem.Index - 1).field`